# Unable to setup virtual host for windows 8 computer (xampp)

Tags: apache, windows-8, xampp, virtualhost

Hi I have been trying for hours with many tutorials and I still not able to get the virtual host running on windows8 platform. I am using xampp 1.8.3. My xampp folder is installed as xampp2 in the c-directory

Step 1: I edited the \System32\drivers\etc\hosts file as such

> 127.0.0.1       xampp.local
>
> 127.0.0.1       localhost

Step 2: I enabled the following lines in httpd.config:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Step 3: I edited \apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp2\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@fountains.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\Sean\Documents\vhostprjs\foods"
    ServerName xampp.local
    ServerAlias www.xampp.local
    <Directory "C:\Users\Sean\Documents\vhostprjs\foods">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Step 4: restarted xampp and tried localhost and it worked. But when I tried www.xampp.local\ chrome complains

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.xampp.local

I really don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code... and edit accordingly in your http-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *
  <VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\your_site_directory"
    ServerName your_site_directory.dev
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\your_site_directory">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And use this in your windows host file without the pound # sign infront

```
127.0.0.1       your_site_directory.dev
```

The directory can be linked from any directory, not specifically from the htdocs folder and the server name can end in .anyname, but be becareful when using .coms and .nets, It may cause confusions while trying to access them.

But in case you still like to use .com or .net, which i usually do. This is how to get around with it, to access a .com you created for yourself (local) in your vitual host, this is how you do it from the address bar

```
http//your_site_name.com
```

And for your external .com

```
http://www.your_site_name.com
```

Comment: Adding `localhost` virtual host in Windows 8 solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using forward slashes instead of backslashes?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@fountains.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Sean/Documents/vhostprjs/foods"
    ServerName xampp.local
    ServerAlias www.xampp.local
    <Directory "C:/Users/Sean/Documents/vhostprjs/foods">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, It was really for painful for me to get it work in Apache 2.4.9.I found a lot of tutorials, but I can not make it work.

MY SOLUTION IS FOR  APACHE 2.4 AND ABOVE VERSION.I have tested it with Apache 2.4.9

You need to edit two files.PLEASE MAKE BACKUP OF THIS TWO FILE BEFORE YOU MAKE CHANGES.If you write anything wrong , your localhost will not work even you uninstall xampp and then again install xampp.

STEP 1:

Edit this file

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Open this file using "Run As Adminstrator" from Notepad(Very Important).You can do this by

Start Menu > Notepad >Right Click > Run As Adminstrator > Open file

add these two lines at the end of this file

```
127.0.0.1       testsite.dev
127.0.0.1       www.testsite.dev
```

Either you go testsite.dev or www.testsite.dev , it will now try to access from your local machine NOT from the web

STEP 2:

E:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

You can edit this file normally , there is no need to run this file as "Run As Adminstrator"
Add the follwing lines at the end of this file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@.testsite.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/htc"
    ServerName testsite.dev
    ServerAlias www.testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I setmy xampp in E drive , so when you copy from here , make sure you change it according to your xampp installation.the Last part is little interesting.I am pointing out this potion

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@.testsite.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:/xampp/htdocs/htc"
    ServerName testsite.dev
    ServerAlias www.testsite.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Where can you find this code?In internet , you can find it in many places but might not work for you as that code will differentiate from your Apache version.SO WHAT"S THE SOLUTION?

At the end of file , you will see there are some commented lines already to show you a demo how to setup virtual host, just copy those lines and make necessary changes and it will work for you.I have attached a screenshot for better understanding

http://postimg.org/image/5pug9f42p/

Answer (score 0):

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.xampp.local

The above error is related to name resolution. Chrome cannot find where the site "www.xampp.local" is. To resolve this, you have to add the fully qualified domain name to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.xampp.local
```

Comment: That did not work. It still says Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.xampp.local

Comment: I changed:

<VirtualHost www.xampp.local:80>

Could not resolve host name www.xamp.local -- ignoring!

Comment: @madi what happens if you `ping www.xamp.local`? also, just a wild guess because I'm not familiar with apache, but what happens if you change `ServerName` value to `www.xamp.local` in the second block?

Comment: Ping request could not find host www.xamp.local. Please check the name and try again. But when i try ping localhost, it shows the reply

Comment: It seems like the windows8 hosts file is malfunctioning. I did some setting with Avira to not block host files from being edited and tried to block 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com to test if host file is working. After typing www.facebook.com on browser, i was still able to go facebook. Does this mean that the host file is not being read by windows?

Comment: I have no problem using the hosts file on Win 8. I assume you are running your file editor with admin privileges?

Comment: Yes I do notepad++ with administrative privilege. I have done all the required settings. No1. Allowed Avira to make changes to Hosts file. No2. Uninstalled Avira and allowed host file to be edited by windows defender. Even doing all this, I tested the host file by adding 127.0.0.1 www.bbc.com. By right my chrome should say page is unavailable or something like that but I am still able to go to www.bbc.com. Does this mean that my hosts file is malfunctioning?

Comment: I even checked the extension of the host file and it was not in txt too.

Comment: Chrome might be using ip6 to connect to the local machine. The only thing I would try is to temporarily disable ip6. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I did the same using firefox too and i stil had the same issues. I will try to disable ipv6 and see. Thank you for helping to give suggestions.